# rounding to closest integer in Apex

Tags: apex, rounding

Will someone help me with understanding rounding within Apex?
Why when I have a value like 96.7 using `Integer result = Math.Floor(96.7)` round to 96?
I am doing calculation and I need to round up or down.
So 96.2 rounds to 96
And 96.7 rounds to 97

I read something about HALF_EVEN but was unsure if this would work since I need to round to the nearest integer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Math.floor` always rounds down, `Math.ceil` always rounds up. Using `Math.round` uses half-even rounding mode, so you can simply say:

```
Integer result = Math.round(96.7);
```

Half-even means that if a value is exactly 0.5, it rounds to the nearest even number (96.5 rounds to 96, 97.5 rounds to 98). This is the most "fair" statistically speaking, but you need to follow other rules, you can:

```
Decimal value = 96.7;
Integer result = value.round(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Which would round up on 0.5 or higher, for example. You can read about all the rounding types [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm).